# Regex email validation after "@"

Tags: javascript, razor

I'm working on a contact form, in the email input field I need to make sure that the user is inputting a correct email address.

I've only found regex that validate the below:
`email@domain` (without the `.com`,`.net`, `.info`, etc)

What regex requires the user to enter the `.com`, `.net`, etc?

Regex I've used:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b

^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9._%+-]{0,63}@@(?:(?=[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$

^(?=[A-Z0-9@@._%+-]{6,254}$)[A-Z0-9._%+-]{1,64}@@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$

^[A-Z0-9._%+-]{1,64}@@(?:[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.){1,125}[A-Z]{2,63}$
```

Comment: And I enter in example.com all the time. lol  https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 0):

In regex a `.` is used to match any character. Escaping the dot as such; `\.` will allow you to match it.

So I guess something like (assuming the beginning already works) could work:

```
\..{3,6}
```